# Como chamar método do Angular 4 em código HTML gerado pelo jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-datatables

Estou usando um template que comprei feito em Angular, porém não está tudo em Angular tem muita coisa em jQuery.

Eu estou usando o Datatable do jQuery (pois já é o nativo do template, está com o css todo pronto e inclusive já está buscando os dados e paginando), porém eu preciso de algumas ações em alguns elementos que preciso (quero) que seja processado pelo angular. Como marcar um checkbox por exemplo.

Eu estou usando o [fnRowCallback do Datatable](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks) para tratar o html. No exemplo abaixo eu gostaria de ao mudar o estado checkbox (html gerado pelo plugin em jQuery) os dados serem enviados para o método changePropertyEnabled (método do componente do Angular)

```
...,
fnRowCallback: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
        const mDataEnabled = '<label class="ui-switch switch-icon">' +
          '<input type="checkbox" (change)="changePropertyEnabled(1, false)">' +
          '<span></span>' +
          '</label>';
        const mDataRemoveIcon = '<a class="text-muted font-16" href="javascript:;"><i class="ti-trash"></i></a>';
        //
        $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(mDataEnabled);
        $('td:eq(6)', nRow).html(mDataRemoveIcon);
        return nRow;
      },
 ...


 changePropertyEnabled(id: number, enabled: boolean) {
    alert('Hello World');
  }
```

Comment: Seu HTML está gerando normalmente? Porque sua chamada com `(change)="changePropertyEnabled(1, false)"` está correta. E existe algum motivo específico de você estar gerando esse HTML dinamicamente pela `function`? Você poderia criar ele normalmente e utilizar um `*NgIf` na chamada da mesma.

Comment: Está gerando sim, mas o change não funciona. Eu acabei encontrado uma solução agora pouco, mas não sei se é o melhor caminho. Eu usei o html estático só para testar mesmo.

Comment: Pois então, talvez esse HTML que ele gere o Angular não esteja conseguindo lidar no nó que ele criou, consequentemente não tratando o `change` mas isso é uma suposição. Talvez gerar ele sem ser estático seja uma boa tentativa.

Comment: @PatrickLima é isso mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const self = this;
    const dtAccount = $('#dt-account');
    dtAccount.DataTable({
      pageLength: 10,
      fixedHeader: true,
      responsive: true,
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: {
        url: this.api.getBaseUri('/service/v1/accounts'),
        type: 'POST'
      },
      fnRowCallback: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
        const mDataEnabled = '<label class="ui-switch switch-icon">' +
          '<input type="checkbox">' +
          '<span></span>' +
          '</label>';
        const mDataRemoveIcon = '<button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-icon-only btn-circle btn-sm btn-thick dt-remove-icon">' +
          '<i class="ti-trash"></i>' +
          '</button>';
        //
        const mAccount = new Account();
        mAccount.fromObject(aData);
        // Custom fields
        $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(mDataEnabled);
        $('td:eq(6)', nRow).html(mDataRemoveIcon);
        // Enabled button
        const mInputEnabled = $('td:eq(0)', nRow).find('input');
        mInputEnabled.prop('checked', mAccount.enabled);
        mInputEnabled.change(function (e) {
          mAccount.enabled = $(this).prop('checked');
          self.changePropertyEnabled(mAccount);
        });​
        // Remove button
        const mButtonRemove = $('td:eq(6)', nRow).find('.dt-remove-icon');
        mButtonRemove.click(function (e) {
          self.deleteAccount(mAccount);
        });​
        return nRow;
      },
      columns: [
        {'data': 'enabled'},
        {'data': 'firstName'},
        {'data': 'lastName'},
        {'data': 'email'},
        {'data': 'created'},
        {'data': 'modified'},
        {'data': 'id'}
      ],
      'sDom': 'rtip',
      columnDefs: [{
        targets: 'no-sort',
        orderable: false
      }]
    });
```

> Com isso eu mantive o self para ser uma referência para o meu componente, para usar tanto em chamadas angular quanto em jQuery

```
const self = this;
```

> Defini em mDataEnabled o botão enable

```
const mDataEnabled = '<label class="ui-switch switch-icon">' +
              '<input type="checkbox">' +
              '<span></span>' +
              '</label>';
```

> Criei um HTML estático que não estava sendo manipulado pelo Angular e inseri no html

```
 $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(mDataEnabled);
```

> Usei o jQuery para recuperar o elemento que eu queria manipular (input)

```
 const mInputEnabled = $('td:eq(0)', nRow).find('input');
```

> Adicionei a lógica de manipulação que eu queria

```
 mInputEnabled.change(function (e) {
          mAccount.enabled = $(this).prop('checked');
          self.changePropertyEnabled(mAccount);
        });​
```

> Usei o self para falar para relacionar a o elemento processada pelo jQuery com Componente do angular.

```
 self.changePropertyEnabled(mAccount);
```

Não sei se é o melhor jeito, mas funcionou. Se tiver outra forma melhor de fazer é só postar que eu agradeço.